# How do I center the entire DataTable in the pdf using JQuery pdfHtml5

Tags: jquery, pdf, datatables, pdfmake

I'm loving using `$('#tableId').DataTable()` and the "pdfHtml5" button to generate a PDF. I just can't figure out how to center the information within the generated PDF.

A Table with only two columns shows up on the left of the .pdf, but would look much better if it were just centered.

I am pretty sure it's supposed to be done in the button, but have not quite figured out the last bit.

Current Example (not quite working):

```
extend:"pdfHtml5",
className: "btn",
text: "Export To PDF",
title: "PDF Title",
filename: "AFileName",
messageTop: "Test Message",

// And this is where I think I'm close...
customize: function(doc) {
    // doc ? = ?
}
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look at `doc`'s `content` section. The second index is the table element. You can force left / right margins with for example

```
customize: function(doc) {
  doc.content[1].margin = [ 100, 0, 100, 0 ] //left, top, right, bottom
}
```

This will center the table, set values according to your needs. Have looked into the docs, and there seem to be no way to automatically "center" page content. There is `alignment` options, but these go for text alignment within the rendered content (for example a table).

Comment: This sounds like exactly the answer I am looking for, but I can't quite figure it out. When I apply the above to my DataTable I see no change in the resultant downloaded PDF.

You say "Look at" but I fear I'm missing that piece too. How can I see the breakdown of the doc and it's contents?
`console.log()` isn't logging anything (in Chrome) on button creation nor on button click

Comment: log `doc` to the console inside `customize()`, see this -> **https://jsfiddle.net/09rd35em/** and the resulting PDF.

Comment: You are 100% correct! 
Thank you for the jsfiddle. That helped me figure out that in my case the content[2] was my table, and content[1] was my "messageTop" (a blank string that was probably being pushed around as expected). So the only further lesson to learn for others like me, your doc.content table may be a slightly different index - depending on how you built it.

Answer (score 1):

I normally use html next I convert to pdf with jquery. Summing up I use Jquery and JsPDF.

But you can get more information here https://datatables.net/reference/button/ .

Comment: Using JsPDF does seem like it would work, and I did come across it when searching for an answer to this - but I have just been advised that the effort of investigating and implementing JsPDF is likely outside of my scope.

Holding out hope for a solution without adding more third party code